# Why create methods which only call other methods?

Tags: java

I am looking at a code which someone else wrote. I do not understand why there are methods which only call another method. I have a class with about 100 methods where most of them look like somthing simillar to this:

```
public void parallel(String str){
    //some code
}
public void prl(String str){
    parallel(str);
}
public void p(String str){
    parallel(str);
}
public void hidden(String str){
    //some code
}
public void hid(String str){
    hidden(str);
}
public void h(String str){
    hidden(str);
}
.
....
```

Why should somone do that? I am thinking of deleting all except those where there is some code.

Comment: To [decorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) the code usually. In this specific example it is useless.

Comment: Very very useless, apparently he did that to have smaller name in his main code but then you don"t what the function do because you don't have an explicit name / you better delete your question, you'll get downote quickly

Comment: If the methods have the exact same implementation, it's just a waste of lines....

Comment: Looks like someone's a lazy typer or can't remember if it's "hidden", "hid" or "h" and just triest to make all of them work. An example of actual names could potentially shed some light on this.

Comment: There isn't really enough detail here to properly answer you. I would **guess** *encapsulation* (or maybe *orthoganality*). Really, your posted example seems pointless.

Comment: I'll call the person and ask why. s/he should have a better reason.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The only thing  which maybe make sense is what @Joachim Sauer says: "lazy typer".

Comment: @Trillian: if that's it, then it's a terrible, terrible reason to do that (and I'd be hard-pressed to find a non-terrible reason to do this). IDEs have autocompletion. There should really only be one name for any given method.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer The devloper isn't here anymore so that i am unable to ask him why. I just wanted to ask some other people before i delete those pointless methods.

Comment: @JoachimSauer the only good reason I can think of is if the short name is a well-known abbreviation in the domain, e.g. an HTML-building library, where `p` exists as a short form of `paragraph`. In such a case, using `p` might make the calling code look more HTML-esque, and thus readable, those familiar with HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's impossible to say what the real reason is in this case, but this kind of thing is pretty common in Java programming. A typical reason is that software maintainers want to change method naming conventions to make names consistent between classes or packages; the hope here is that it will make class usage easier to remember. But it's difficult to get rid of the old methods, because other code may rely on them still being there. That's why we still have, for example, in Java AWT, `Container.insets()` and `Container.getInsets()`, which do precisely the same thing. At some point, somebody decided that methods that only return data ought to have names that begin with `get`, so a whole pile on new, duplicate methods was introduced, and most (all?) the old ones are still there.

There's a whole slew of classes in the JVM runtime library that have pairs of methods with names like `xxxHtmlyyy` and `xxxHTMLyyy` that do exactly the same thing. Conventions about how methods names that contained abbreviations changed, but the old methods have to be retained, because a lot of existing code still uses them.

In an ideal world, we probably wouldn't have to deal with this sort of thing, but real software management is a compromise between many different needs.